# Hey stack overflow problem regarding laravel api in expo react

Tags: laravel, api, react-native, expo

[image: undefined this is the main problem] API is working just fine but it shows the undefined response in alert box help regarding this is really appreciated. login object returned status code token correctly but when it comes to alert box it always shows undefined I don't know why.I attached a screenshot of the console and emulator. I think i miss something been stuck on this problem since 3 days no solution found online.[image: Response from the api and data is correct]

```js
import React , {useState} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,Text,Keyboard,StatusBar
} from 'react-native';
import {Container,Header,Input,Label,Content,Title,Card,CardItem,Button,Body} from 'native-base';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  const [email,setEmail] = useState();
  const [password,setPassword] = useState();

  myfun = async()=>{
    //alert(email);
    await fetch('http://172.31.40.233/p.o/api/v1/user/login',{
      method:'POST',
      headers:{
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        //'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({"email":email,"password": password})
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(resData =>{
      alert(resData.message);
      console.log(resData);
    });
  }
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle = "dark-content"/>

      <Container>
        <Content>
          <Header>
            <Title>
              Login
            </Title>
          </Header>
          <CardItem header>
            <Text style ={styles.heading}>Login with Laravel API</Text>
          </CardItem>

          <CardItem>
            <Input placeholder = "Email" style={styles.input}
            value = {email} onChangeText={(value) => setEmail(value)}
            />
          </CardItem>


          <CardItem>
            <Input placeholder = "Password" style={styles.input}
            value = {password} onChangeText={(value) => setPassword(value)}
            />
          </CardItem>


          <CardItem>
            <Body>
            <Button primary block onPress = {myfun}>
              <Text style = {styles.btn}>Login</Text>
            </Button>
            </Body>
          </CardItem>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: You alert `resData.message` but there's nothing here to indicate that you are getting this field in the response

Answer (score 0):

You can test your api using postman and then use it in app, in this way you can debug api and app separately.if postman doesn't return data then paste your laravel function code here